# How can I Compiling and running Multi-Device Application in Delphi xe7?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

I am a beginner. I am using Delphi XE7. I have built a 32 bit Windows application successfully without any error. Now I want to learn/create an Android application, so I have tried to compile and run some sample project. But every time I have a problem compiling these projects.

1. I have installed a USB driver for my GT-I8552B
2. Samsung GT-I8552B supports NEON (second generation), ARMv7
3. Android SDK manager/SDK tool with ARM EABI v7a System Image  installed in my desktop computer (included with XE7).
4. My phone's OS version 4.4.1 and I am using 32 bit Windows 7 on my PC.

I have enabled USB Debugging and try to compile a project, but an error occurs:

```
[DCC Fatal Error] Project1.dpr(1): F2048 Bad unit format: 'c:\program files\embarcadero\studio\15.0\lib\Android\debug\System.dcu' - Expected version: 28.0, ARM(ARM) Found version: 0.0, Windows Ansi(x86)
```

[image]

I have added an AVD and run it in the Android Emulator, but the same error occurs:

[image]

How can I compile and run a Multi-Device Application in Delphi XE7?

This the library path - $(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release;$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports;$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDSCOMMONDI‌​R)\Dcp;$(BDS)\include;C:\Program Files\FastReports\LibD21;C:\Program Files\Raize\CS5\Lib\RS-XE7\Win32 . Search path default value from Debug . Please tell me details how can I repair system.dcu for android compiler or which will the correct path of system.dcu for android  ?

Comment: How did you get to this state? How did you corrupt that dcu? Perhaps you should do a reinstall.

Comment: I don't know , somehow this system.dcu was corrupted . Now my problem is solved by reinstall xe7 . Thanks everybody here .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler is complaining that the `System.dcu` file it found was compiled for Win32 instead of Android.  It is very unlikely that the Android version of `System.dcu` was compiled for Win32.  So either your search paths are not configured correctly, or you probably messed up your IDE installation.

Comment: Same System.dcu is working for also for win64 . But does not work for android . this the library path - $(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release;$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports;$(BDS)\Imports;$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp;$(BDS)\include;C:\Program Files\FastReports\LibD21;C:\Program Files\Raize\CS5\Lib\RS-XE7\Win32 . Search path default value from Debug . Please tell me details how can I repair system.dcu for android compiler or which will the correct path of android system.dcu ?

Comment: The System.dcu is different for **each** platform and therefore the dcu files are kept in different `$(Platform)` folders. So it is **not the same** dcu working for win32 and win64